# centos 7 report warning lvmetad message

Tags: linux, centos

recently i have updated centos 7.1 to 7.3, today when i modify /etc/default/grub.cfg, try to execute grub2-mkconfig, it will report "WARNING: Not using lvmetad after response error.". Then i also try to use vgscan/lvscan. It also reports same warning message.

```
[root@jrfm1 centos]# lvscan
  WARNING: Not using lvmetad after response error.
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos/swap' [13.62 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos/home' [71.85 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/centos/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
```

I have tried to google, but no new clue how to resolve it. And got message, it may let system boot failed. Any idea to resolve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl restart lvm2-lvmetad
```

I found restarting the lvmetad service can resolve that issue.